# How do I extract the second audio channel from the first audio stream from an MP4 file

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to extract the second audio channel from the first audio stream from an MP4 file. The first stream of the MP4 is a data stream , the second stream is stereo audio and the third stream is video. So the file is a bit atypical.

This is a command I use for mapping:

```
 ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -map 0:a:1 -map_channel 0.1.1 outfile.wav
```

The map_channel relies however on specific index numbers. How can I map audio channels without knowing indexes or probing the file first.

Answer (score 1):

Think I found a solution:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a1]" -map "[a1]" outfile.wav
```

This works no matter where the audio stream is positioned.